# How to create a JAXB project in IntelliJ IDEA 13?

Tags: intellij-idea, jaxb

I am learning JAXB. 
I need to know how should I create a simple java project for JAX-B in IntelliJ IDEA13. If anyone have idea, please update me and also update me with any plugin for IDEA

Thanks.

Comment: What does that mean? Jaxb plugin? Or do you want to generate classes from xsd or wsdl?

Comment: I am just learning very basic jaxb ...marshalling and unmarshalling using XSD and XML

Comment: I have a project created which uses SpringMVC, Hibernate and Maven. I have an XSD File for which I have to create JAX-B Classes in IntelliJ.

Comment: Then look at this example: https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools-example - and use **cxf-xjc-plugin** for xsd->java generation

Comment: Hello Meo, How to install these plugins in IntelliJ and use it. Any documentation available for the same

Comment: Those are Maven plugins, not IntelliJ plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special when you create your project. **Just a simple java project will do.**

There are however some tricks that can help you. **There are 2 built-in live templates for jaxb** :

1. typing `mjo` + hit tab-key: will generate the code for a marshaller.
2. typing `ujo` + hit tab-key: will generate the code for an unmarshaller.

**Intellij has built-in functionality for generating an `xsd` file** for any `xml` file. Just right-click on any `xsd` file and you will see a button *"Generate xsd schema from xml file"*.

**JAXB also offers a tool (`xjc.exe`) to generate JAXB code stubs. There is a simple way to add this functionality to IntelliJ.** I prefer to add a button for `xsd` to java source conversion, using the configuration in the *"External Tools"* menu.

[image: Configuration of external tool]

**After this configuration, you can right-click on an xsd file and there will be a button *"JAXB (XSD->JAVA)"*.**

Note: According to some websites, there is also a dialog/wizard for generating jaxb stubs. However, I haven't found this wizard yet. Maybe it's only available in more recent IntelliJ versions (14+), maybe only in the commercial edition, or it may require some plugins. **My solution works fine in IntelliJ 13.0.3 - Community Edition.**