# I can't see Jaxb tools in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I'm going crazy. I want to generate jaxb classes from a XSD in intellij, but I don't have the option in tools/jaxb or with right click in the file.
I read that I need a "webservices" plugin, but I don't see it.
Sorry if my english is bad.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a solution that apparently works with the community edition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32902555/399435

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Community edition of Intellij don't have this option, that's the problem :P

To anyone with this problem, you can use Eclipse for free JAXB.

Comment: I have ultimate but I do not see the menu anyway;
as @Ganesh Krishnan says, make sure you have selected the tab with the .xsd file open.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Ultimate Version of IntelliJ Idea to do this as JAXB doesn't seem to be supported by Community Edition.

In Ultimate Version make sure you open the file (And not just select it in the navigator). It's kind of counter-intuitive as I expected Tools menu to change based on what I have selected rather than opened but that's just me.

tldr: Make sure the file is open in editor and not just selected in navigator to see the JAXB menu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an xml file thoses instructions should help [Generating Instance Document from Schema Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-instance-document-from-xml-schema.html) But they dont seem to include any right click.

If you really need to generate a class with your IDE, I can only tell you that Eclipse doesn't do that on it's own. I had to use a maven plugin to accomplish that.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. The link you're posted has nothing to do with the question and referring to Eclipse does not help and is incorrect as there are Eclispe plugins which invoke XJC.